# How to get data from <center></center> tags on an external site using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the text from [this website](http://pi.karmona.com/) which is just a simple string of 10 million digits of pi. I'd like to turn this into a Javascript variable, preferably using jQuery, but I'm not sure how. Is there a simple and easy way to do this? (It doesn't matter that I'd get "Pi - 10 million digits" with the string too, I can fix that later)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Since PI is a mathematical constant, why not just copy it and hardcode it? Either way, I cannot imagine why on earth you want to do this! :)

Comment: I'm building a program to turn words into letters, and search for them in pi (http://codepen.io/Random_Pseudonym/pen/EWvdge). As for hardcoding, I'm a coding noob who hasn't moved off Codepen yet, which doesn't let me use that many characters.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty cool! Fair enough then!

Comment: @H.Mitchell, are you looking for something like this - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XMZoyW

Comment: Is #output meant to hold pi? I can't see anything unfortunately

Comment: yes @H.Mitchell, it holds complete Pi value and appended to #output

Comment: I am trying in chrome browser and it looks fine for me

Comment: Really weird. Something about the function isn't working for me, and I'm on chrome too. Wonder what's making the difference...